# How to create gradient object with Raphael

Tags: javascript, object, svg, raphael, gradient

I was trying to use Raphael JS graphics library. I would like to use the attribute gradient which should accept an object. Documentation says to refer to SVG specs. I found the gradient object in SVG, for instance

```
<linearGradient id="myFillGrad" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
<stop offset="5%" stop-color="red" />
<stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="0.5" />
</linearGradient>
```

but how can I reference that from within my javascript?

```
circle.attr("gradient", "myFillGrad");
```

doesn't work :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** Rewritten for the latest Raphael API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Linear Gradient</title>
  <script src="http://raphaeljs.com/raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 600);
    var circle = paper.circle(150, 150, 150);
    circle.attr({
      "fill": "90-#f00:5-#00f:95",
      "fill-opacity": 0.5
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The documentation for the new `attr()` API is found [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#attr).

Comment: It looks like this API doesn't exist anymore. See http://jsfiddle.net/GuQA6/ for a test case.

You don't happen to know the new API for altering opacity of color stops, do you?

Comment: I've updated the code sample to reflect the latest API. Your best bet in the future is to read the documentation to find out how the APIs have changed.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to match @NathandeVries code sample... http://jsfiddle.net/GuQA6/155/ just for the next dev that wants to see it in action.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe the current raphael API allows you to set the individual stop opacities other than the last one, which is given the value passed in to the "opacity" attr, for example:

```
this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "r(.5,.1)#ccc-#ccc", opacity: 0})
```

...will have an stop-opacity of 0 on its last stop. For finer-grained control I added this "case" to the attribute parsing switch in my raphael.js:

```
 case "opacityStops":
                            if (attrs.gradient) {
                                var gradient = doc.getElementById(node.getAttribute(fillString)[rp](/^url\(#|\)$/g, E));
                                if (gradient) {
                                    var stops = gradient.getElementsByTagName("stop");
                                    var opacs=value.split("-");
                                    for(var ii=0;ii<stops.length;ii++){
                                        stops[ii][setAttribute]("stop-opacity", opacs[ii]||"1");
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
```

You must also add a corresponding entry in the "availableAttrs" object, for example:

```
availableAttrs = {<other attrs here>..., opacityStops:"1"}
```

A call to create a circle with a radial gradient with different opacity stops would then look like:

```
this.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "r(.5,.5)#fff-#fff:70-#000", "opacityStops": "1-0-0.6"}
```