# Fill property in raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to create a sphere in Raphael which should look like
[image]

I am using `Paper.ellipse` with equal horizontal and vertical radius to draw sphere.
I think I need to tweak `fill` attribute to achieve effect as shown in image. Also I want sphere in different color with same effect.
Can anybody point out any helpful link about `fill` property in Raphael as I couldn't find enough information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used

```
function ball(x, y, r, colour) {
    paper.ellipse(x, y, r, r).attr({
        fill: "r(.3,.25) white-" + colour,
        stroke: "none"
    });
};
```

You can use any color like `yellow` or color code like `#00CC33` for hue.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UKUeE/2/embedded/result/).
[Demo Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/UKUeE/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the source of this page: http://raphaeljs.com/ball.html. Basically, it consists in drawing several ellipses to simulate a single enlightened sphere.

You can learn more about gradient in Raphael on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575747/how-to-create-gradient-object-with-raphael).