# Draw Rod shaped cylinder with raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to draw  a rod like structure with raphael js, giving it gradient effect so that it will show a 3-d effect.
But as I am just a beginner I am not able to achieve this thing.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Hey Shruti -- there are probably a couple of ways that could be accomplished.  Can you update your question with a link to an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually I want to draw an armature just like the moving one shown on this page http://www.rdpe.com/displacement/lvdt/lvdt-principles.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you what I know.  You'll want to fill your object with a gradient.  I've made a few rectangles for you to look at.  Play with them, and understand how the gradient fill works.  That's what I did.  :)

```
var paper = Raphael("holder");
paper.setSize(400, 400);
rect = paper.rect(25, 50, 25, 300).attr({fill: "180-#FFF:10-#f00:80-#000:95"});
rect = paper.rect(100, 50, 25, 300).attr({fill: "0-#FFF:10-#f00:80-#000:95"});
rect = paper.rect(175, 50, 25, 300).attr({fill: "90-#FFF:5-#f00:80-#000:95"});
```

The first number in the fill is the rotation of the fill.  The numbers following the colors (ex. #FFF:5) is the offset.

Here's a similar question with some good answers/information:  [How to create gradient object with Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575747/how-to-create-gradient-object-with-raphael)

Comment: I wanted something like paper.rect(50,150,300,50).attr({fill:"90-#000:5-#fff:55-#000:95"}); and  had done with your help. Thank you

Comment: @Shruti glad to have helped.  If this answered your question, then please mark it as the answer.  Also, be certain to look at your other questions.  If a good answer is provided that you are satisfied with, then mark it as an accepted answer.